# Calculate values from multiple number fileds - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate price based on quantity and price and calculating a subtotal by adding all products prices.

### below is the code of html

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input min="0" data-unit-price="9.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input min="0" data-unit-price="19.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3><span class="se-curency">$</span><span data-sub-total="0" id="se-sub-total" class="se-total-amount">0</span></h3>
        <h3><span class="se-curency">$</span><span id="se-vat" class="se-total-amount">8</span></h3>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I am trying The below js

---

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'input', '.se-ticket-qty', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    jQuery(this).each(function(i){
        var unit_price = jQuery(this).data('unit-price');
        var amount = jQuery(this).val();

        var current_sub_total = parseFloat(unit_price);

        sum += current_sub_total;

        var sub_total = jQuery('#se-sub-total').attr('data-sub-total');

        var final_sub_total = parseFloat(sub_total) + sum;
        jQuery('#se-sub-total').attr('data-sub-total', final_sub_total.toFixed(2));
        jQuery('#se-sub-total').html(final_sub_total.toFixed(2));
    });
    console.log(sum);
});
```

But There is an error in calculating.The sub total is working fine if I use upper arrow in number field.But if i use below arrow or input an number by manually it is not working.

Comment: I haven't gone through a thorough debugging, but am I right in thinking the jQuery(each) on line 3 will only go through one item, the item that triggered the event listener on line 1? That's the only "this" at the time it runs. I think it should select the original selector again to get all of them.

Comment: Yes its not a problem..But problem is with counting..

Comment: If i don't use each same thing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just had a few small issues with how you were using each logic and adding up the totals. Here is a snippet that does what I think you were trying to do. Just un-comment the console.logs to see how the order of operations changed how the final sum is calculated. I am not sure what you wanted with the second display with 8$:

```js
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
   console.log( "ready!" );
        
   $(document).on('input', '.se-ticket-qty', function(){
     CalculateTotal();
   });
});

function CalculateTotal(){
  var sum = 0;
      
  $(".tableWithInputs").find( ".se-ticket-qty" ).each(function( index ){
    var unit_price = parseFloat($(this).data('unit-price'));
  var amount = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var totalPrice = unit_price * amount;
  //console.log("unit_price: " + unit_price);
  //console.log("unit_price: " + unit_price);
  //console.log("amount: " + amount);
  //console.log("totalPrice: " + totalPrice);

        sum += parseFloat(totalPrice); 
      });
      
      $('#se-sub-total').attr('data-sub-total', sum.toFixed(2));
      $('#se-sub-total').text(sum.toFixed(2));
      //console.log(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableWithInputs">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input min="0" data-unit-price="9.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input min="0" data-unit-price="19.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <h3><span class="se-curency">$</span><span data-sub-total="0" id="se-sub-total" class="se-total-amount">0</span></h3>
        <h3><span class="se-curency">$</span><span id="se-vat" class="se-total-amount">8</span></h3>
    </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Here its working fine but in my code there is `NaN` Why this is occuring?

Comment: Uncomment the console.log sections and see where the issue is happening. Did you copy the entire script or just change the parts that are different?

Comment: The NaN output simply means that the value is Not-a-Number. It is a common error when the parseFloat recieves something other than a real number.

Comment: Yes I copied the same...The Problem is `.se-ticket-qty` is a DOM element which is loaded after page load through An ajax call.Thats why `NaN` is being shown

Comment: Just for testing then try to replace the $( ".se-ticket-qty" ) selector in the each function with $( ":input" ) to see if that selector is not working.

Comment: Or you could wrap the inputs in a div that is there on page load and use $(".currentDiv").find(".se-ticket-qty"). That would allow you to access the inputs after initial page load.

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to access the inputs if they are loaded after initial page load.

Comment: Did that work for you? Maybe you could mark as answer if that worked for you.

Comment: Its `NaN` as before :(

Comment: Oh! Working Now.Thanks A Lot